# PLC cooperate with Modbus Gateway failed

Tags: network-programming, wireshark, modbus, plc

**Background:**
The plan tries to use Modbus gateway to enable multiple masters to communicate with multiple slaves.The gateway would package Modbus RTU data as TCP/IP data.
Like the image shows below.

[image]

The network has two gateway, one work as TCP Client another work as TCP Server.
Every Modbus master uses a different serial port on the gateway, and it would use different TCP port to connect the same TCP server(gateway).

**Problem:**
One PLC can read through the gateway to get slaves data correctly, while HMI keeps alerting the communication error. They use different serial ports from the gateway.

**What I tried:**
When using a software to simulate a Modbus master, it can read the data.
And when the HMI connect directly with Modbus slaves, they can communicate.
The serial settings are same, on every device.
When using software simulating, also used `Wireshark` to diagnose the network. Most frames are `[TCP ACKed unseen segment]`, some say it's what could be ignored. The Modbus data in these frames are correct like shown above.

[image]

Totally have no clue now, any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: It's totally unclear what the problem even is. "HMI keeps altering the communication error" doesn't make sense.

Comment: @GilHamilton sorry, it's not "altering", it's alerting.After HMI connect to the gateway, it can't read slave device information.

Comment: `[TCP ACKed unseen segment]` typically means wireshark is only seeing traffic in one direction. But here, it looks like wireshark is seeing both directions; it's just totally confused about the TCP sequence numbers. It appears that both sides are incrementing sequence numbers / acks in lock-step but (from wireshark's POV), the sequence numbers for the two directions do not match up (they should). That indicates something weird, but I can't say what exactly. Maybe something wrong in the TCP/IP implementation in one or both of your gateways?

Comment: @GilHamilton I agree, your comment confirmed my speculation.